# Why does AWK give an error on this conditional statement?

Tags: awk

In the second awk one liner , I simply switched the `<` for `>` and it gave me a syntax error. Are we not allowed to use `>` in conditional statements?

```bsh
~/Desktop $ awk 'BEGIN{print 3<5 ? "Hello":"World"}'
Hello
~/Desktop $ 
~/Desktop $ awk 'BEGIN{print 3>5 ? "hello": "world"}'
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN{print 3>5 ? "hello": "world"}
awk: cmd. line:1:                 ^ syntax error
~/Desktop $
~/Desktop $ awk 'BEGIN{print 5<3 ? "Hello":"World"}'
World
~/Desktop $
~/Desktop $
```

Answer (score 5):

The `print` statement in `awk` takes one of three forms:

- `print > expression`
- `print >> expression`
- `print | expression`

... where the `>`, `>>`, and `|` bit, and the `expression` that follows, are optional.

The `print > expression` command will cause the output to go to a file named by whatever string that `expression` evaluates to.  If the file exists, it will be truncated (emptied).  This is similar to how output redirection in the shell works, but the file will not be truncated by executing the same `print` statement a second time, unless `close(expression)` is used to close the file related to `expression` first.

The `>>` and `|` forms of the `print` command are also inspired by how the shell handles these tokens but see an `awk` manual for further information about these forms.

In your code, you have

```c
print 3 > 5 ? "Hello" : "World"
```

This matches the `print > expression` syntax and would therefore output the string `3` to a file called `5`.  The rest of that line continues with a question mark, which your `awk` can't make much sense out of, so it complains about it. Some `awk` implementations would use the `5 ? "Hello" : "World"` bit as the `expression` and would therefore write `3` to a file called `Hello` (since `5` is a *true* value when used as a boolean).

What you most likely wanted to do is

```c
print ( 3 > 5 ? "Hello" : "World" )
```

or

```c
print ( 3 > 5 ) ? "Hello" : "World"
```

This ensures that the `print > expression` syntax isn't triggered.

Comment: FWIW in GNU awk there's a 4th form of `print` which is `print |&` for communicating with a coprocess.

Answer (score 2):

Use text only for your demos.

Use parentheses around your expression:

```bsh
$ awk 'BEGIN{print (5>3 ? "Hello":"World")}'
Hello
$ awk 'BEGIN{print (3>5 ? "Hello":"World")}'
World
```

May be, `>` character is interpreted like a redirection to a file for print command

Comment: Note that with `BEGIN{print 3>5 ? "Hello":"World"}`, `mawk` and `busybox` `awk` do write `3` to the file called `Hello`, while some others need `BEGIN{print 3>(5 ? "Hello":"World")}` for that.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has an unparenthesized ternary expression [possibly] on the right side of output redirection. There are 2 issues with that:

- An unparenthesized expression on the right side of output (or input)
  redirection is undefined behavior per POSIX so never do that.
- An uparenthesized ternary expression is harder to read than one with
  parentheses and can lead to syntax errors in some awks in some
  contexts so never do that either.

Bad:

```
print > foo bar
getline < foo bar
str = x>y ? foo : bar
```

Good:

```
print > (foo bar)
getline < (foo bar)
str = (x>y ? foo : bar)
```

When creating multiple output files, though, it's usually a good idea to close them as you go and then you would store the output file name that's the result of the expression in a variable and then you don't need parens, e.g.:

```
out = foo bar
print > out
close(out)
```

So your code:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print 3<5 ? "Hello" : "World"}'
awk 'BEGIN{print 3>5 ? "hello" : "world"}'
awk 'BEGIN{print 5<3 ? "Hello" : "World"}'
```

which, depending on what it's supposed to do, is either not using parens on the right side of output redirection or not using parens around a ternary or both and so should instead be written as:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print (3<5 ? "Hello" : "World")}'
awk 'BEGIN{print (3>5 ? "hello" : "world")}'
    or, less likely, awk 'BEGIN{print 3 > (5 ? "hello" : "world")}'
awk 'BEGIN{print (5<3 ? "Hello" : "World")}'
```